# replica connection to mongo in Compute Engine from Cloud Function with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have a mongodb server running on Compute Engine with master, slave and an arbiter. I am able to connect to one of mongo server from GCF with mongoose simply with a string connection such as `mongodb://user:pass@ip1:port1/db?authSource=admin`. Note ip1 is the external IP of mongo VM.

Now the problem is, I get an error when I put my replica connection such as `mongodb://user:pass@ip1:port1,ip2:port2/db?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs_name` where ip1 and ip2 are external IP for master and slave.

It gives error like

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb0-server-1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb0-server-1 mongodb0-server-1:27017]

From what I can see it's more like DNS issue where it failed to resolve the address but I am not so sure. If that's the case why it only happen when replica set is given? Where do I need to look for this issue?

Comment: `mongodb0-server-1` is the hostname. You need to use the full dns name.

Comment: Hi where can I get the DNS name? As I mentioned above I put down the IP address and port instead of hostname. I am not sure as well how it resolved to a hostname from my given IP address.

Comment: From your mongodb server or from the person that configured it. The more details that you provide the better the answers. You have not specified what the mongodb server is, where it is located or how it is configured.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have added the configuration with master and slave running on GCE.